# set sequence of functions with .when and .done in jQuery

Tags: jquery, function, callback

trying to display data only after variables have been set.

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    function setdata() {
        var mydata = '123';
    };

    $.when(setdata()).done(function () {
        $(".content").text(mydata);
    });
});
```

Comment: Setting variables is already synchronous, there is no need to use `$.when()`.

Comment: I have a function that seems to be operating before the variables are set; I'm trying to ensure there's a proper sequence

Comment: If you have such a function, it is apparently not being called in your `ready()` handler.

Comment: What do you think that code is suppsed to do? `setdata` does not return a promise object, why is it being passed to `$.when`? the `$.when` will return a resolved promise object if you don't give it a promise object and the `.done` will be called immediately since it is already resolved. Sure, it will work, but it is pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `$.when` in this case since you aren't actually passing it a promise object.

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    var mydata;
    function setdata() {
        mydata = '123';
    };

    setdata();
    $(".content").text(mydata);
});
```

Is `setdata` doing more than what you are showing in your question? I'm guessing it does an ajax request, in which case it should look like this:

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    function setdata() {
        return $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
    };

    setdata().done(function(mydata){
        $(".content").text(mydata);
    });
});
```